# Regular expression for multiple of 100

Tags: html

Can anybody provide me regular expression for multiple of 100.

we want to validate value in multiple of 100 .

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: As a string, this is incredibly basic and you could work out with a quick search/basic regex cheat sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use this:

```
^[1-9]+[0-9]*00$
```

First number must be from 1 to 9, then any number of random digits, and it must end in two 0's.

In future looking up a bit of regex would be a good first step, this is very very simple and can be worked out (even by a complete novice) in very little time.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it work for me ,is it possible to provide constant value through regular expression.

Comment: prefect. worked finally from millions answers

Answer (score 4):

what about this

```
([0-9]*00)|0
```

you can check above expression [here](http://www.regexpal.com/)

Comment: That would allow "000" as a multiple of 100.

Comment: @DBS but 000 is a multiple of 100,
100 * 0 = 0,
am i wrong?

Comment: I guess that's technically true, but in common circumstances and uses, I would expect that people would refer to multiples of 100 as 100 and up. I guess it depends what the poster wants from the expression.